# Porque se modifica la fecha en sql server?

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime, pyodbc

Tengo un input en angular el cual seleccionas una fecha y se manda a una api en python, hasta ahi llega bien.
La api en python la guarda en una tabla en sqlserver usando PYODBC, pero al checar la base de datos, me modifica la fecha.

Si secciono 2023-02-08 al llegar a SqlServer, aparece 1905-07-06.

Tambien cree una fecha con el comando "datatime.now()" que deberia ser 2023-02-08
Y se guarda 1894-07-09.

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el query como tal que al final ejecutas y el tipo de dato exacto de la columna fecha?

Comment: Lo que a mi me ha pasado con otros lenguajes es que aunque el dato que se esta guardando sea de tipo **Date** o **DateTime** en ocasiones no tiene el formato exacto y por default pone esa fecha

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estás manejando los datos de forma incorrecta, pero sin ver el código no sé donde esté el problema. Como ejemplo, si ejecutamos el siguiente código en SQL Server

```
SELECT CAST( 2023-02-08 AS datetime)
```

No va a identificar el `2023-02-08` como fecha sino como una expresión numérica que se reduce al valor entero `2013`, el cual es el valor equivalente a `1905-07-07` en SQL Server.